# How to compare a List of words (chr) to values in multiple columns in a dataframe and output a binary response if there is a match in R

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, text-processing

I want to compare each individual word in the **words** column to the values in columns **V1** **to V576** (row wise for every row) . If any word from the **words** column matches any of words in the **V** columns, replace the word in the respective 
**V** column by 1 or else by 0 if no match. Any idea how to do it? *I am not sure how to loop this over all the rows and columns*

Dataframe is called **Data**.
Column **words** is a list ($ words :List of 42201). There are 42201 rows
There are around 576 Columns of words to be compared (V1 to V576).

**here is the dput file of the first 3 rows and first 20 columns only.**

```
structure(list(id = c("Te-1", "Te-2", "Te-3"), category = c("Fabric Care", 
"Fabric Care", "Home Care"), brand = c("Tide", "Tide", "Cascade"
), sub_category = c("Laundry", "Laundry", "Auto Dishwashing"), 
    market = c("US", "US", "US"), review_title = c("the best in a very crowded market", 
    "first time", "i have been using another well known brand and did not expect    "
    ), review_text = c("the best general wash detergent  convenient container that keeps the product driy ", 
    "this helped to clean our washing machine after getting it from someone else   this review was collected as part of a promotion  ", 
    "i have been using another well known brand and did not expect much difference  wow  was i ever mistaken  i will never go back "
    ), review_rating = c(5L, 5L, 5L), words = list(c("the", "best", 
    "general", "wash", "deterg", "conveni", "contain", "that", 
    "keep", "the", "product", "driy"), c("this", "help", "to", 
    "clean", "our", "wash", "machin", "after", "get", "it", "from", 
    "someon", "els", "this", "review", "was", "collect", "as", 
    "part", "of", "a", "promot"), c("i", "have", "been", "use", 
    "anoth", "well", "known", "brand", "and", "did", "not", "expect", 
    "much", "differ", "wow", "was", "i", "ever", "mistaken", 
    "i", "will", "never", "go", "back")), V1 = c("absolut", "absolut", 
    "absolut"), V2 = c("action", "action", "action"), V3 = c("actionpac", 
    "actionpac", "actionpac"), V4 = c("actual", "actual", "actual"
    ), V5 = c("addit", "addit", "addit"), V6 = c("adverti", "adverti", 
    "adverti"), V7 = c("afford", "afford", "afford"), V8 = c("agent", 
    "agent", "agent"), V9 = c("allerg", "allerg", "allerg"), 
    V10 = c("allergi", "allergi", "allergi"), V11 = c("alon", 
    "alon", "alon")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000023d166a1ef0>)
```

Please see below a snippet of how the data frame looks like to understand my question better

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DATA TABLE]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Images are a bad way of posting data. Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(DATA[20, 5])`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have added the dput file in the question. The dput only contains first 3 rows and first 20 columns. Would this be okay?

Comment: You could look into mutate_if() from the `dyplr` package

Comment: @ist123 would you be able to write a code example for me? Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a dataframe

## data

```
data <- data.frame(words = c("the, best, general","i, have, been"), v1 = c("best","no"), v2 = c("have", "nothing"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Using for loop condition I have passed the function grepl  where ever it matches it comes appears 1 if not 0

```
for (i in 2: ncol(data)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
  
  x <- i
  
  y <- data$words[j]
  
  ab <- data [j,x]
  
   abc <- grepl (ab , y)
    
   data[j,i] <- ifelse (abc %in% "TRUE", 1, data[j,i])
    
  }
}
```

## result

```
print (data)
        words       v1     v2
the, best, general  1      0
   i, have, been    0      0
```

Comment: I made a small change in your code and it works!:

data[j,i] <- ifelse (abc %in% "TRUE", 1, 0)

Comment: @OnyekaD'mello Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to show you how to create a reprex of your problem, i created a new example of your data and provide a code, using tidyverse that I think answer your question.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  words = c("I want to compare each individual word in the words",
            "column to the values in columns V1 to V576",
            ". If any word from the words column matches any",
            "replace the word in the respective V column by 1 or else"),
  v1 = c("want", "want", "want", "want"),
  v2 = c("word", "word", "word", "word"),
  v3 = c("any", "any", "any", "any")
  )





df %>%
  gather(key = key, value = value, -words) %>%
  mutate(appear = as.numeric(str_detect(words, value))) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(key, appear)
```

**output**

```
                                                     words v1 v2 v3
1          . If any word from the words column matches any  0  1  1
2               column to the values in columns V1 to V576  0  0  0
3      I want to compare each individual word in the words  1  1  0
4 replace the word in the respective V column by 1 or else  0  1  0
```

Comment: Hello Johan! Thank you for your help but this did not work. I did not understand the output:

                                         words    v1    v2    v3
1          . If any word from the words column matches any FALSE FALSE FALSE
2               column to the values in columns V1 to V576 FALSE FALSE FALSE
3      I want to compare each individual word in the words  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4 replace the word in the respective V column by 1 or else FALSE FALSE FALSE

Answer (score 0):

And in addition to the tidyverse-solution by @Johan Rosa, here is a solution that works with base-R:

```r
ls <- lapply(1:nrow(yourFrame), function(row){
  out <- as.numeric(yourFrame[row,] %in% unlist(yourFrame[row,'words']))
  names(out) <- names(yourFrame)
  return(out)
})
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, ls))
```

The `lapply`-call loops through every row of your data.frame and creates a boolean vector for each one, determining whether the word-vector of the respective row can be found again while keeping the column-names from before.
The last call just glues it all together.

Comment: Hello Max! Thank you for your feedback but unfortunately, it did not work :( See the output below

  words    v1    v2
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE FALSE FALSE

Comment: I changed the output to numeric values, just for completeness sake. Does that solve your problem?